# Why are there so many exceptions in my device log from FingerprintManager?

Tags: android

When I connect my phone to Eclipse, I see tens of thousands of logcat messages in my device (Samsung S2) log.
Most of them are exceptions from FingerprintManager.

I am concerned because when I debug my application, my logcat buffer fills up fast and wipes out my application logs (even when I increase buffer size).

**Is it a bug in the android framework, or just in the device manufacturer's software, or something else?**

```
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:145)
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:612)
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:613)
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:542)
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:377)
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at dwh.a(PG:216)
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at dvu.a(PG:120)
05-03 10:22:20.948: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:79)
```

another...

```
05-03 10:23:24.460: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:377)
05-03 10:23:24.460: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at dwh.a(PG:216)
05-03 10:23:24.460: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at dvu.a(PG:120)
05-03 10:23:24.460: E/iu.FingerprintManager(8012):  at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:79)
```

Even if you use a filter, runtime exceptions thrown will not be caught by the filter.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I believe it is on topic and have edited my post to clarify why I am concerned.

Comment: If the `FingerprintManager` is not part of your application you can filter out those log messages by adding a filter for your applications package name in Eclipse.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Even if you filter out those log messages, the exceptions affect the overall buffer which will wipe out your filtered log messages.

Comment: No they won't the buffer is just in Eclipse because the log messages are coming in to fast. That happens when you don't filter and Eclipse can't handle that. The log messages are correctly stored on your phone, it's just a display problem in Eclipse.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I assure you that I am filtering. This is a concern for me and it is a valid question to ask if it is a bug in the android framework, or just in the device manufacturer's software, or something else.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Even if you use a filter, runtime exceptions thrown will not be caught by the filter. Please do not downvote in ignorance

Comment: I'm having the same errors. Ok I can filter them out. I dont know what it is but it cant be very good. @ android 4.4.4 Motorola E.